# Is blessing the Ubuntu partition reversible on a Macbook Pro? How?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, partitioning, macbook, multi-boot

So far, I've been dual booting Mac OS X with Ubuntu.

Blessing the Ubuntu Partition will speed up the boot process. Apparently, all I have to do is this:

> `sudo bless –device /dev/disk0s3 –setboot –legacy –verbose`

**How can one reverse this command?**

Comment: This question, as João Pinto pointed out below, is possibly off-topic because you are asking for support with Mac OSX. Although you have a separate Ubuntu partition on your machine, the focus of your question is on the Mac `bless` utility, which we probably can't help you with.

Comment: Perhaps this could be migrated to http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If anyone wants to follow, here's the same question posted at the apple stack exchange: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30607/is-blessing-the-ubuntu-partition-reversible-on-a-macbook-pro-how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"bless" is not a Ubuntu/Linux utility, so is not something we can help you with, probably you will get better help by asking in a Mac OS x support resource.
I general if you don't understand how a command works you should not run it.